# How to get different connection for different browser session/machine so I can get different profile feeds?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social-facebook

I followed tutorial on:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/

I run the application and successfully authenticate with a single user. Home page returns my feeds.

Now I connect to the application from another browser/machine and go to home page - I see feeds of first browser session/machine.

**I am expecting to be asked to log in again when connecting from different browser/machine.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Didnt try it, and depends on exact configuration :
When you logged in on the first browser you gave facebook the permission to allow your application to access your facebook account.
If you are logged in to facebook before on the other browsers with the same user, the permission given to the app through interaction on the first browser might be sufficient.
You can try to use incognito mode on a browser, in this case you should definitely have to authorize again.

Comment: this is not about incognito mode, it is about getPrimaryConnection returning get(0) every time. I don't understand why the concurrent users login is not a default preset(as it would be logical, imagine spring security which would just authenticate one user and every other browser/machine coming to webapp sees profile of a previously logged in user - this would be ansurd). I use facebook-starter which must have sane preset configuration which apparently does not.